# Different ways of saying “ I am not following the conversation” when someone is speaking and ask you a question but you are absent minded?

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-usage

The following options cone to my mind
1. Sorry, I am not following you. 
2. Sorry, I did not get that.
3. I am sorry, can you repeat that?
4.Say that again!

Please advise for more options, especially official ones!

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to be honest you could say, "Sorry, I was not paying attention."

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pay_attention

"Sorry, my mind was wandering." That's another option.